# H2 No suitable driver found for jdbc:h2:mem:

Tags: java, h2

I am trying an example of using H2. But I cannot create an in-memory DB. When I run the following program, I just get an error message:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:h2:mem   at
> java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
> at
> java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:251)
> at db.DBExample.main(DBExample.java:14)

In pom.xml I included

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
   <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.200</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Anybody knows what is wrong?

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class DBExample {
    public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {

        var url = "jdbc:h2:mem:";
        try (var con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
             var stm = con.createStatement();
             var rs = stm.executeQuery("SELECT 1+1")) {
             if (rs.next()) {
                 System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
             }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            var lgr = Logger.getLogger(DBExample.class.getName());
            lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is because you have specified `<scope>test</scope>`.
Remove the scope line.

> This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for normal use of the application, and is only available for the test compilation and execution phases.

```java
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
   <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.200</version>
</dependency>
```

Have a look here : [driver not found](https://dev.to/rohithv07/driver-class-not-found-com-sap-cloud-db-jdbc-driver-5fmb)

Comment: Interesting, test scope is present if you copy it from maven central [maven central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2/2.1.214). Thank you